RpcError: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Inability to pay some fees , e.g. account balance too low
I created this script to set the validator keys via a CLI using an environment variable file and Polkadot.js Tools without having to change its CLI to load the seed from a file instead of just a string value as suggested here, and without exposing the seed in the terminal logs.

Note: I already know how to rotate and keys and perform the setKeys transaction using Polkadot.js Apps in Staking > Account Actions, as mentioned here, and I also already know how to do it via the Validate tab mentioned here, but I want to try and do it via CLI instead as a challenge.

I am running the validator on Tangle Testnet with the following:
/usr/bin/tangle-testnet-linux-amd64 \
  --base-path /path/tangle-testnet/data-path/validator/luke1 \
  --name luke1 \
  --chain tangle-testnet \
  --node-key-file "/path/tangle-testnet/data-path/validator/luke1/node-key" \
  --port 30333 \
  --validator \
  --no-mdns \
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 1"

But when I follow the steps to set the session keys using that script on same machine as the validator is running on, where the environment variables in the .env file included the 127.0.0.1 as the IP address of that validator (I also unsuccessfully tried its public IP address and 0.0.0.0), the session key from running the curl request with method author_rotateKeys, and the seed of the account running the validator node, but it outputs:
API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: Abnormal Closure

I tried adding the options --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-cors=all --rpc-methods=Unsafe and restarting the validator, but it still gave the same error.
So then I ran the script from another machine after changing the environment variables in the .env file to include the public IP address of the server that was running the validator, the session key from running the curl request with method author_rotateKeys,  the seed of the account running the validator node, but that returned the following error:
RpcError: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Inability to pay some fees , e.g. account balance too low

I had an adequate account balance shown at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Ftestnet-rpc.tangle.tools#/accounts before doing all this, but apparently that page was not working and the Tangle team are investigating.
The server logs don't show any errors:
Tangle Node
✌️  version 1.0.2-e909dea-x86_64-linux-gnu
❤️  by Webb Technologies Inc., 2023-2024
 Chain specification: Tangle Testnet
  Node name: luke1
 Role: AUTHORITY
 Database: RocksDb at /<PATH>/tangle-testnet/data-path/validator/luke1/chains/tangle-testnet/db/full
 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
   Local node identity is: 123
  Operating system: linux
  CPU architecture: x86_64
  Target environment: gnu
  CPU: AMD EPYC 7713 64-Core Processor
  CPU cores: 4
  Memory: 7932MB
  Kernel: 6.5.0-21-generic
  Linux distribution: Ubuntu 23.10
  Virtual machine: yes
  Highest known block at #200265
 Running JSON-RPC server: addr=0.0.0.0:9944, allowed origins=["*"]
 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615
  Starting BABE Authorship worker
  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip4/1.2.3.4/tcp/30333/p2p/123
 ✨ Imported #200266 (0xf130…7cc1)
 ✨ Imported #200267 (0x578e…7b32)
 ✨ Imported #200268 (0x85ba…e650)
 Discovered new external address for our node: /ip6/.../tcp/30333/p2p/123
 Idle (5 peers), best: #200268 (0x85ba…e650), finalized #200266 (0xf130…7cc1), ⬇ 21.5kiB/s ⬆ 11.2kiB/s


I still believe your account is low on funds. Could you fetch and share the System::Account(seed_account) details here? Also, please display $args[1] to verify that you're passing the correct value.

so i believe the error was because RPC endpoint wss://testnet-rpc.tangle.tools was actually not working, but it does show my correct account balance using their replacement endpoint wss://testnet-rpc-direct.tangle.tools. i think it is because the binary tangle-testnet-linux-amd64 of their latest v1.0.2 release that i'm using https://github.com/webb-tools/tangle/releases/tag/v1.0.2 has bootNodes property values that only include that old endpoint. so to make it work i'd have to build latest release v1.0.2 from source and change bootnodes to use latest endpoint if i knew what they were

I noticed you're using Frontier. Which version of Frontier are you on?
